# How do I perform a conversion of raw Unicode Hexadecimal into Unicode representation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, unicode, encoding

I am not able to convert hexadecimal unicode encoding e.g. from C/C++/Java source code

```
0022
```

into its propper representation:

```
"
```

My return value is not represented in MATLAB's Command Window.

What am I getting wrong? How do I get my file encoded and shown in Unicode representation?

Also see the reference here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/charset_support.htm.

Comment: *What am I getting wrong?* You are not using the functions as stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:

```
char(hex2dec('0022'))
```